# Significance of the term "London town"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning

I have heard multiple instances of "London town" in Gwen Stefani's song Rich Girl, and in a commercial for the second Garfield movie (just a TV spot, not a trailer).

I want to know what it means and the significance of it. It's confusing because London is a huge city with a monstrous airport and lots of people.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are other anomalies. How many people live in Greenwich Village? How many green fields and duckponds does it have?

Comment: I'm under the impression that, technically speaking, "London Town" refers to the portion of downtown London that contains the old financial district.  Of course, a songwriter is not constrained by such technicalities, and "London town" sounds better than just "London" in many cases.

Comment: @HotLicks You are thinking of the term '[City of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London)'.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Yeah, you're probably right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**London town** is a colloquial expression to refer to modern London in a way that evokes traditional sentiments, to a time where it wasn't as populated.

[Nicknames of Places: Origins and Meanings of the Alternate and Secondary Names, Sobriquets, Titles, Epithets and Slogans for 4600 Places Worldwide](https://books.google.com/books?id=H8dWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22london+town%22&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm1Neu5IXOAhWL6IMKHVdECyw4FBDoAQhWMAk)

> "London Town London, England. A form of the British capital's name found mainly in ballads and popular songs, as well as more generally in poetry. It emphasizes the city's quintessen- tially urban nature."

[LOST YOUTH: LONDON, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=LdLucXuWu6wC&pg=PA14&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx3rW45YXOAhVl6oMKHbqfD4M4PBDoAQhUMAg#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[Slicing the Moon: A Guided Poetic Excursion](https://books.google.com/books?id=3Q8Kr5uLU1QC&pg=PA70&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz8bGy5oXOAhVi44MKHTGzBu84RhDoAQhWMAk#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[Cycling Britain](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3utlbrmxcEC&pg=PA41&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx3rW45YXOAhVl6oMKHbqfD4M4PBDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[Thou Kingdom Come Robert J Monk is God's Secret Agent: Book of Revelation ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=oiLhXGl1-f4C&pg=PA54&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiviPfl54XOAhXB7YMKHfRZCBI4oAEQ6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[A Dictionary of British Folklore, 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=YkwTR64_q00C&pg=PA409&dq=%22london+town%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg7--s2IXOAhXI5IMKHWbUASkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[The Record Players: DJ Revolutionaries](https://books.google.com/books?id=9fJCAJ-UqRYC&pg=PT36&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi17L6s54XOAhWqz4MKHUyfA5M4UBDoAQhUMAg#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[A Dictionary of Victorian London: An A-Z of the Great Metropolis](https://books.google.com/books?id=uFD5kBdg_LgC&pg=PA140&dq=%22london+town%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg7--s2IXOAhXI5IMKHWbUASkQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[Abbreviations Dictionary, Tenth Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=t3fLBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1334&dq=%22london+town%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg7--s2IXOAhXI5IMKHWbUASkQ6AEISzAI#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[Dictionary of Contemporary Quotations (English)](https://books.google.com/books?id=bpILAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA288&dq=%22london+town%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg7--s2IXOAhXI5IMKHWbUASkQ6AEIUjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia: Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=NVFAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA6407&dq=%22london+town%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3lo2X2oXOAhXMyoMKHf19AiQ4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[Mary Poppins, She Wrote: The Life of P. L. Travers](https://books.google.com/books?id=5S05AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz8bGy5oXOAhVi44MKHTGzBu84RhDoAQgtMAI#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[The Scots Fiddle: (Vol 1) Tunes, Tales & Traditions of the North-East ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=4gYhbdO7MIcC&pg=PA41&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj997qZ6IXOAhVMw4MKHdhAD0A4ggEQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[Life in London Or the Day and Night Scenes of Jerry Hawthorn, Esq. and His ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=505pL_b9D2IC&pg=PA18&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF453T6IXOAhXB4IMKHQZQBWo4ChDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[The bar-sinister, or, Memoirs of an illegitimate [signed C.E.L.].](https://books.google.com/books?id=stsDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNuM3y6IXOAhUC5oMKHQmjBOc4FBDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[The History of the Life and Heroic Actions of the Renowned Sir William ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=wlVCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA135&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNuM3y6IXOAhUC5oMKHQmjBOc4FBDoAQguMAI#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[The Legendary Cabinet: A Collection of British National Ballads, Ancient and ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=5KBgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9-Yus6oXOAhVq44MKHcmSC6k4KBDoAQgpMAE#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

[The Hive - A Collection Of the Most Celebrated Songs - vol IV](https://books.google.com/books?id=pP1eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP14&dq=%22london+town%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLjsH-6oXOAhVFxoMKHc9gBkwQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22london%20town%22&f=false)

[image]

So you wouldn't use the phrase if you weren't a native of U.K.

Comment: Also worth noting that London has engulfed many of the surrounding towns.  For example, I think Kensington was a distinct town at one time with fields between it and London.  But you are right about the modern use to evoke an older time.

Comment: Wow... That's a lot of examples! Thanks for clearing that up for me! :)

Comment: I'd use the phrase, and I'm not a native of London, but the use would be jocular and possibly slightly disdainful, as those of us in the provinces can often be about old London Town.

Comment: @Spagirl ~ good point; I should have said "native of U.K." and not London :)

Comment: @TrevorD ~ appreciated, Mr. D :)